# Problem with arithmetic expressions with years in queries

Tags: python, django

It looks like django doesn't create a correct MySQL query when having a simple arithmetics with ExtractYear().

I have a model with two data fields:

```
class Event(models.Model):
    start_date = models.DateField()
    finish_date = models.DateField()
```

If I want to find all rows such that the years of start_date and finish_date are equal, I can do it so:

```py
from django.db.models import F
from django.db.models.functions import ExtractYear
>>> print Event.objects.annotate(year=ExtractYear(F('start_date'))).filter(finish_date__year=F('year')).only('pk').query
SELECT `event`.`id`, EXTRACT(YEAR FROM `event`.`start_date`) AS `year` FROM `event` WHERE EXTRACT(YEAR FROM `event`.`finish_date`) = (EXTRACT(YEAR FROM `event`.`start_date`))
```

But if I want to find events that start and finish in consequent years, I try the following filter, and it gives me an incorrect MySQL query:

```py
>>> print Event.objects.annotate(year=ExtractYear(F('start_date'))).filter(finish_date__year=F('year')+1).only('pk').query
SELECT `event`.`id`, EXTRACT(YEAR FROM `event`.`start_date`) AS `year` FROM `event` WHERE `event`.`finish_date` BETWEEN 0001-01-01 AND 0001-12-31
```

I tried to replace `F('year')+1` with `F('year')+Value(1)` but it didn't help.

1. Am I wrong somewhere, or does it look like a bug in django?
2. I will also be grateful if you see any other methods to do the same!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what finally worked:

```py
Event.objects.annotate(diff=ExpressionWrapper(ExtractYear(F('finish_date'))-ExtractYear(F('start_date')), output_field=IntegerField())).filter(diff=1).only('pk').query
```

Looks like there is a bug in django. I added it to https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/30494 .

Answer (score 1):

The query seems to be legit.

However, an alternative query worked in my case:

```
Event.objects.annotate(s_year=ExtractYear(F('start_date')), f_year=ExtractYear(F('finish_date')), diff=F("f_year")-F("s_year")).filter(diff=1).only('pk')
```

Just annotated a start_date, finish_date and diff.

Comment: what Django version are you using? In my 1.11, your code
`Event.objects.annotate(s_year=ExtractYear(F('start_date')), f_year=ExtractYear(F('finish_date')), diff=F("f_year")-F("s_year")).filter(diff=1).only('pk')`
returns `FieldError: Cannot resolve keyword 's_year' into field`, and if I divide it into to different annotations: `Event.objects.annotate(s_year=ExtractYear(F('start_date')), f_year=ExtractYear(F('finish_date'))).annotate(diff=F("f_year")-F("s_year")).filter(diff=1).only('pk')`, I get `TypeError: expected string or buffer`. :(

Comment: I am using 2.0.